# Java - ImageIO not getting picture

Tags: java

I am trying to add the image sprite_sheet.png to my game project but I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at az.rehman.gfx.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:16)
at az.rehman.game.Game.<init>(Game.java:29)
at az.rehman.game.Game.main(Game.java:127)
```

Here are my classes:

```
package az.rehman.gfx;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class SpriteSheet {
public String path;
public int width;
public int height;

public int[] pixels;

public  SpriteSheet(String path) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("SpriteSheet file exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(image == null)
        return;

    this.path = path;
    this.width = image.getWidth();
    this.height = image.getHeight();

    pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);

    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = (pixels[i] & 0xff/64);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        System.out.println(pixels[i]);

    }


    } // constructer end




} // class end








package az.rehman.game;

import az.rehman.gfx.SpriteSheet;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WIDTH = 160;
public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
public static final int SCALE = 3;
public static final String NAME = "Game";

private JFrame frame;

public boolean running = false;
public int tickCount = 0;

private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

private SpriteSheet spriteSheet = new SpriteSheet("\\sprite_sheet.png");

public Game() {
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

    frame = new JFrame(NAME);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
}


public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double nsPerTick = 1000000000D / 60D;

    int ticks = 0;
    int frames = 0;

    long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double delta = 0;


    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
        lastTime = now;
        boolean shouldRender = true;
        while (delta >= 1) {
            ticks++;
            tick();
            delta -= 1;
            shouldRender = true;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (shouldRender) {
            frames++;
            render();
        }

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000) {
            lastTimer += 1000;
            System.out.println(ticks + " ticks, " + frames + " frames");
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }

    }


}

public void tick() {
    tickCount++;

    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = i + tickCount;
    }


}

public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Game().start();
}

}
```

Comment: As is usually the case in these types of questions, your path to the sprite sheet is probably incorrect. If you're getting resources, then the path should be relative to the class files.

Comment: if you want to make sure you don't mess up the path just drop the sprite sheet in the root of your project and access it like "sprite_sheet.png"

Comment: Are you running from a .jar file?  Does `path` contain the name of an entry in that .jar file?  Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) so you’re clear on when the path should and should not start with a slash (`/`)?